# Date names localization in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I parse the site and get a date like this:

```
2021. május  7., péntek, 15:17
```

I realized that Python has this format:

```
%Y. %B %d., %A, %H:%M
```

But when I specify it, an error occurs, I think it's because of the months and days of the week in Hungarian since my locale is in English.
Error:

```
ValueError: time data '2021. május  7., péntek, 15:17' does not match format '%Y. %B %d., %A, %H:%M'
```

Actually, the question is, can I change the locale on the fly in the datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**Ex:**

```
import dateparser

s = "2021. május  7., péntek, 15:17"
print(dateparser.parse(s))
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-07 15:17:00
```

---

Or setting `locale`

**Ex:**

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "hu_hu") # Hungarian
import datetime

s = "2021. május  7., péntek, 15:17"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y. %B %d., %A, %H:%M"))  # 2021-05-07 15:17:00
```